# How to take objects from arrays and put them in a single array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have the following code which is returning me an array with other three arrays instead returning an array with objects only. Any way to get that done?

Here is the returning response where I would like to keep just the main Array with objects only

```
Array [
  Array [
    Object {
      "_id": "5b276afd8d05600a78e91fea",
      "description": "",
      "location": Array [
        Object {
          "_id": "5b276afd8d05600a78e91feb",
          "city": "London",
        },
      ],
      "postDate": "2018-06-18T08:18:16.893Z",
      "title": "Post Michael 1",
    },
    Object {
      "_id": "5b276c35bab2220ae8ec8859",
      "description": "",
      "location": Array [
        Object {
          "_id": "5b276c35bab2220ae8ec885a",
          "city": "London",
        },
      ],
      "postDate": "2018-06-18T08:18:16.893Z",
      "title": "Post Michael 2",
    },
  ],
  Array [],
  Array [
    Object {
      "_id": "5b27a44b91b02c10450fef7e",
      "description": "",
      "location": Array [
        Object {
          "_id": "5b27a44b91b02c10450fef7f",
          "city": "London",
        },
      ],
      "postDate": "2018-06-18T12:23:32.508Z",
      "title": "Post Sarah 1",
    },
  ],
]
```

Here is my function thats returning this

```
export function getAllJobs(dispatch, getState) {
  const state = getState();
  const { token } = state.auth;
  return axios.get(JOBS_ALL_URL, {
    headers: { authorization: token }
  }).then((response) => {
    var result = [];
    response.data.map(o => {
      result.push(o.jobs);
    });
    console.log(result);
    dispatch(setJobs(result));
  }).catch((err) => {
    dispatch(console.log("Couldn't get jobs."));
  });
}
```

Comment: With `.reduce`, `.map`, `.concat` or even spread operator `...`. Give these a google search.

Comment: @Adelin thanks a lot